# Using the following code it populates all cells in the table that are blank

Tags: vba, excel

I have the following code and it works great except for one thing when it is used it finds every blank field in the table and inserts the value of the field above it.  I only need it to fill the fields above the rows that were inserted by the code.

```
 Sub ERCACMPCleanup()

'Cleans ERCA_CMP Worksheet and creates extra records for comma delimited

  Dim X As Long, LastRow As Long, A As Range, Table As Range, Data() As String
  Const Delimiter As String = ", "
  Const DelimitedColumn As String = "A"
  Const TableColumns As String = "A:O"
  Const StartRow As Long = 2
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ERCA_CMP").Visible = True
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ERCA_CMP").Activate
  LastRow = Columns(TableColumns).Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlFormulas).Row
  For X = LastRow To StartRow Step -1
    Data = Split(Cells(X, DelimitedColumn), Delimiter)
    If UBound(Data) > 0 Then
      Intersect(Rows(X + 1), Columns(TableColumns)).Resize(UBound(Data)).Insert xlShiftDown
    End If
    If Len(Cells(X, DelimitedColumn)) Then
      Cells(X, DelimitedColumn).Resize(UBound(Data) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Data)
    End If
  Next
  **LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, DelimitedColumn).End(xlUp).Row
  On Error Resume Next
  Set Table = Intersect(Columns(TableColumns), Rows(StartRow).Resize(LastRow - StartRow + 1))

  If Err.Number = 0 Then
    Table.SpecialCells(xlBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
    Columns(DelimitedColumn).SpecialCells(xlFormulas).Clear
    Table.Value = Table.Value
  End If
  On Error GoTo 0**
End Sub
```

The issue is in the last few rows this code needs to only fill the blanks in the inserted rows not all blank fields in the table.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is VBA not vbscript.

Comment: Did you try to debug and see why is it going to the rows which are not required by you? Check the conditions and modify it accordingly

Comment: @Nimesh - I do not know vba very well and I am stuck on this I really need to know what I would need to change about this code to only fill in the blank cells for rows where there is a value in column A but blanks in Columns B through O.  The code need not change any other blanks in the table. I know where in the code this function takes place I just don't know what I need to put in there to limit the fields it should change to only be those where the row meets the condition of value in column A but Blanks in B through O.  This is the code that needs changed:

Comment: Set Table = Intersect(Columns(TableColumns), Rows(StartRow).Resize(LastRow - StartRow + 1))

  If Err.Number = 0 Then
    Table.SpecialCells(xlBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
    Columns(DelimitedColumn).SpecialCells(xlFormulas).Clear
    Table.Value = Table.Value
  End If

Answer (score 0):

Modified the code to check if all cells in B:0 are null. I think intersect would not be correct in this case as you don't want to apply this to all the cells.
**Note 1:** There would be better solution than this too as I'm not familiar with complete VBA
**Note 2:** If you put `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` you should set it to `True` at the end of the program too.

```
Sub ERCACMPCleanup()

'Cleans ERCA_CMP Worksheet and creates extra records for comma delimited

  Dim X As Long, LastRow As Long, A As Range, Table As Range, Data() As String
  Dim flgval As Boolean, rcntr As Integer, ccntr As Integer, rownum As Integer
  Const Delimiter As String = ", "
  Const DelimitedColumn As String = "A"
  Const TableColumns As String = "A:O"
  Const StartRow As Long = 2
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ERCA_CMP").Visible = True
  ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("ERCA_CMP").Activate
  LastRow = Columns(TableColumns).Find(What:="*", SearchOrder:=xlRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlFormulas).Row
  For X = LastRow To StartRow Step -1
    Data = Split(Cells(X, DelimitedColumn), Delimiter)
    If UBound(Data) > 0 Then
      Intersect(Rows(X + 1), Columns(TableColumns)).Resize(UBound(Data)).Insert xlShiftDown
    End If
    If Len(Cells(X, DelimitedColumn)) Then
      Cells(X, DelimitedColumn).Resize(UBound(Data) + 1) = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Data)
    End If
  Next

 'Modification Start for the question
 'flgval turns true if cells B:O are not empty
  flgval = False
  Range("A1").Activate
  For rcntr = 0 To LastRow - 1
    For ccntr = 1 To 14
        If ActiveCell.Offset(0, ccntr).Value <> "" Then
            flgval = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
    If flgval = False Then
        For ccntr = 1 To 14
            ActiveCell.Offset(0, ccntr).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
        Next
    Else
        flgval = False
    End If
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Activate
  Next

  '**LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, DelimitedColumn).End(xlUp).Row
  'On Error Resume Next
  'Set Table = Intersect(Columns(TableColumns), Rows(StartRow).Resize(rownum - StartRow))

  'If Err.Number = 0 Then
  '  Table.SpecialCells(xlBlanks).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-1]C"
  '  Columns(DelimitedColumn).SpecialCells(xlFormulas).Clear
  '  Table.Value = Table.Value
  'End If
  'On Error GoTo 0**
  Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: This code is not copying the cell above those that are blank in the newly added rows.  The value that is in Column A must remain the same. So the cells remain blank with your new code.

Comment: the code is not working as expected it is not filling columns B through O with the cell above it.

Comment: @C.R.West it's working in my case. Can you share a file with sample data having the same scenario that you currently have?

Comment: how do I get my test file to you?

Comment: You can upload on Google drive or Onedrive,  enable sharing for that particular file and share the link here, or take a screenshot and attach here

Comment: I was able to find another way to skin the cat.  In this case I could just change the Blank values to read "No Data" to continue to use my initial code.  thank you for your help

Comment: @C.R.West Okay, in that case this post is not required can be deleted as this was a specific question for your needs and would not benefit others